# How can I find what Resources a Java EE container provides?

Tags: java, documentation, java-ee, specifications

How can I find what "Resources" a Java EE container provides? Can I discover this programmatically, or is there documentation I should refer to? (Note that the Java EE tutorial is vague on this subject.)

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

> I was reading the Java EE 6 documentation for [Using the Timer
>   Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html),
>   and I noticed that it doesn't really explain what the TimerService
>   technically *is*. If you read the documentation, you eventually see an
>   example that a TimerService is obtainable using the `@Resource`
>   annotation.
>
> From this I take it that a TimerService is a Resource provided by the
>   container. If it weren't for the example, I never would have realized
>   this without reading a third-party blog post: at no point does the
>   official tutorial say that "TimerService is a container-provided
>   Resource". TimerService is very useful, so I would like to know what
>   other Resources are available.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a third-party blog post, and the official Java EE tutorial is just that, a tutorial: it's not comprehensive. And I briefly checked the Java EE 7 Platform JSR, but I couldn't find a reference to TimerService.

Is there a way to programmatically find the Resources a container provides, or is there a documented list of Resources a Java EE container *must* provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're under a bit of misconception here. First, divorce the `@Resource` annotation from `javax.ejb.TimerService`. Now read the following excerpt from the JavaEE api:

> The Resource annotation marks a resource that is needed by the application. **This annotation may be applied to an application component class, or to fields or methods of the component class**. When the annotation is applied to a field or method, the container will inject an instance of the requested resource into the application component when the component is initialized. **If the annotation is applied to the component class, the annotation declares a resource that the application will look up at runtime.**

What that implies is that *anything* can be declared a resource, to be injected by `@Resource`. The annotation can be used to inject anything, ranging from primitive `<env-entry/>` definitions in the web.xml, to various connection managers (Java Mail, Datasources e.t.c) and it is done on-demand

Typically, it's items that are eligible for JNDI-based access, that are injected using `@Resource`. What this means is that, you need to have a JNDI name, to address a resource before going to look for it (the default value of the name element is the field name
qualified by the class name). [JSR-250](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/caj-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), which defines the `@Resource` annotation lists all the viable targets for that annotation.

If however, you're confident you really want to know everything that the container *might* be able to inject, you could try [listing all available JNDI entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324937/code-to-list-all-the-entries-in-jndi-on-remote-machine). I don't recommend it.

---

As for TimerService in specific, a container *must* provide an implementation of TimerService in order to be JavaEE compliant. This is a quote from [JSR 345](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr345/index.html):

> The container must provide the implementation of the TimerService,
>   Timer, and TimerHandle interfaces.

If you look at the table of contents of JSR 345, you'll see that TimerService gets a chapter to itself, at the same level as topics like "Security Management". This just goes to show that while TimerService may feel like a utility class, it's arguably at the same level of abstraction as any other container-provided service

If you're looking for an authoritative list of mandatory container-provided services, the spec is the place to look. Knowing which spec to look at can be tricky, but as TimerService is in the `javax.ejb` package, the EJB spec is a good guess.

Comment: I was under a misconception, thank you! I need some time to think through your answer, but I will mark it as "correct" in a day or two.

Comment: I'm not sure how "anything can be declared a resource" is incompatible with "what resources does a JavaEE container provide?". Especially with the recent focus on CDI (@Inject), and the abstract nature of JNDI (it's just a string to get "things" from the container) it's not clear at all how it all works as a whole.

Comment: The point I'm trying to communicate @marcus, is that `@Resource` is not a reserved category of components, like the TimerService is

Comment: Yes, that was a misconception on my part. I thought Resources were a special type of component. My line of thinking was "`TimerService` is pretty useful, but what the heck _is_ it? It looks like a utility class. Maybe 'Resources' are utility classes. Does JavaEE have 'utility classes'? Are there others I may not have heard of?" In my opinion, `TimerService` is still a bit of an oddball in JavaEE.